# Find a closed form recurrence relation $T(n) = 3T(n - 2) + 2T(n - 3) + 4$; $T(0) = 0$, $T(1) = 0$, $T(2) = 5$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

For two ordered linear recurrence relation is − $F_n= AF_{n−1}+ BF_{n−2}$ where $A$ and $B$ are real numbers.

The characteristic equation for the above recurrence relation is −

$x^2−Ax−B=0$.

However, I don't know how to solve when $F_{n-3}$ is involved. Kindly help

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

It is the same situation as for a linear differential equation: the solutions are obtained solving first the homogeneous linear recurrence:
$$T(n) = 3T(n - 2) + 2T(n - 3),$$
then adding to the general solution of this homogeneous recurrence equation an particular solution of the non-homogeneous recurrence.

- The solutions of a recurrence of order $3$ are a $3$-dimensional vector space. We first seek for solutions of the form $q^n$, where $q$ is a root of the (cubic) *characteristic equation*:
  $$x^3=3x+2,\quad i.e.\enspace x^3-3x-2=0.$$
  This particular equation is easily solved by the *rational roots theorem*.
- If you have  $3$ simple roots, you obtain a basis of the vector space of solutions of the homogeneous recurrence, $\{q_1^n,\:q_2^n,\:q_3^n\}$.

  If you have a simple root $a_1$ a double root $q_2$, you must complete the linearly independent system$\{q_1^n,\:q_2^n\}$ by a third (independent) solution, $nq_2^n$.

  If you have a triple root, a basis will be $\{q^n,\;nq^n,\:n^2q^n\}$.
- The non-homogeneous equation as a stanard r.h.s. – a constant, so you may try another constant as a particular solution.

Answer (score 0):

You must solve the homogenceous equation
$$t_n=3t_{n-2}+2t{n-3}$$ by the Ansatz $$t_n=q^n$$ and then you have to find a Special solution of the inhomogeneous equation for this make the Ansatz $$t_{n_p}=a+b\times 2^{n+c}$$